# Listen to speaker through output device on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microphone, speakers

I'm on a Windows 10 PC, I've plugged in a USB microphone, and I would like to listen to myself as I record through my device. I enabled "listen to this device" in the microphone settings, but I experience latency issues in doing so. I found a proposed solution [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/audio-delay-problem-in-windows-10/47145328-1b02-4513-82a7-aec668b5d059) that said to disable the "listen to this device" setting, and to enable the microphone option in the speaker properties. However, my microphone does not have a sound card built in, so this option did not work for me. I was wondering whether it would be possible to listen to the speaker through my default output device without any latency.

Comment: It's difficult. Some vendors may have feature that allows you to hear your own voice from the headset. This can greatly reduce latency. We could only try to reduce Microphone sensitivity. Select the "Levels" tab to modify.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

With a dedicated external mic preamp, you can usually listen with little or no delay, as the circuit path is likely to be analogue at that point.

Once you're plugged into your computer, whether analog or via USB, your signal must go through the computer's DACs [Digital Analog Converter] once on the way in, then again on the way out. Each of these processes takes time - some computers/DACs are faster than others, some people use some form of ASIO, either the official from Steinberg or the unofficial [ASIO4ALL](http://www.asio4all.org) which are faster than Window's built-in process, but none are zero latency.